# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined angular

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, set, undefined

How i can fix this error?
login:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaHwu.png)
header:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKbtc.png)
service:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9xj8.png)
error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HkjQ.png)

I want to get id of email setter in login from DB

Comment: Please share your code as text instead of image. This will make it easier for others to read and help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that **this.data2[i]** & **this._auth.author** must not be undefined. In this case, each must be an object that contains the property **email**